# Doctrine deadlock when two users vote themselves concurrently

Tags: symfony, doctrine, deadlock

I have a problem with a Symfony 3.4 application where users can vote entries from other users. It uses FOSRestBundle for APIs and Doctrine for data persistance. The code is very simple:

```
public function voteEntryAction(Request $request, ChallengeEntry $challengeEntry)
{
    /** @var User */
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $em   = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $challengeVote = $em->getRepository(ChallengeVote::class)->findOneBy([
        'user'           => $user,
        'challengeEntry' => $challengeEntry,
    ]);

    if ($challengeVote) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('User has already voted for this challenge entry.');
    }

    $challengeVote = new ChallengeVote();
    $challengeVote
        ->setUser($user)
        ->setChallengeEntry($challengeEntry)
    ;

    $form = $this->createForm(ChallengeVoteType::class, $challengeVote);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($challengeVote);

        // updates the statistics
        $user->addGivenChallengeVote($challengeVote); // <=== here and the next line are the problematic lines

        $challengeEntry->getUser()->addReceivedChallengeVote($challengeVote); // <=== here and the previous line are the problematic lines

        // SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
        $em->flush();

        return $user;
    }

    return $this->view($data, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Sometimes I receive this error:

`SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`

I was able to reproduce the bug, it happens **when 2 users simultaneously vote themselves**. This is because each user is updating the other. How can I solve this?

I tried the following options:

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION 1**

I added another `$em->flush` before the other user's update. Not optimal but it seems to work:

```
// updates the statistics
$user->addGivenChallengeVote($challengeVote);

$em->flush();

// adds a different flush for the other user in order to avoid the following error:
// SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
$challengeEntry->getUser()->addReceivedChallengeVote($challengeVote);

$em->flush();
```

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION 2**

I already tried catching the `RetryableException` and doing the flush again but I receive the error `The EntityManager is closed`.

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION 3**

I tried resetting the EntityManager with `$em->resetManager()` but then all the entities are detached and even the user is considered new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the *double flush* solution was not reliable so I had to **reset the entity manager** and retrieve all the entities again.

The problem were the **current user** and the `ChallengeEntry` object in the method signature. I had to save their IDs and retrieve them again after the deadlock.

This solution is not very pretty but it seems pretty solid. If you have better ideas or solutions please let me know.

I also provided a fallback for the mobile application with a special error code so that the request can be retried entirely.

Here is the full code:

```
public function voteEntryAction(Request $request, ChallengeEntry $challengeEntry)
{
    $retryCount = 3;
    $deadlock   = false;

    /** @var User */
    $user   = $this->getUser();
    $userId = $user->getId();

    $challengeEntryId = $challengeEntry->getId();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $retryCount; ++$i) {
        try {
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();

            // gets the user and the challenge entry after the deadlock
            if ($deadlock) {
                /** @var User */
                $user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->find($userId);

                /** @var ChallengeEntry */
                $challengeEntry = $em->getRepository(ChallengeEntry::class)->find($challengeEntryId);
            }

            return $this->voteEntry($em, $user, $challengeEntry, $request);
        } catch (RetryableException $e) {
            $deadlock = true;

            usleep(200000); // 200 milliseconds
        }
    }

    $data = new ErrorApiResponse(ErrorApiResponse::DEADLOCK_ERROR, 'A concurrency error occurred, please try again later.');

    return $this->view($data, Response::HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
}


private function getEntityManager()
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // resets the entity manager
    if (!$em->isOpen()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    }

    return $em;
}

private function voteEntry(ObjectManager $em, User $user, ChallengeEntry $challengeEntry, Request $request)
{
    $count = $em->getRepository(ChallengeVote::class)->countByUserAndChallengeEntry($user, $challengeEntry);

    if ($count > 0) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('User has already voted for this challenge entry.');
    }

    $challengeVote = new ChallengeVote();
    $challengeVote
        ->setUser($user)
        ->setChallengeEntry($challengeEntry)
    ;

    $form = $this->createForm(ChallengeVoteType::class, $challengeVote);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($challengeVote);

        $event = new ChallengeEntryVotedEvent($challengeVote);
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(ChallengeEntryVotedEvent::NAME, $event);

        // updates the statistics
        $user->addGivenChallengeVote($challengeVote);

        $challengeEntry->getUser()->addReceivedChallengeVote($challengeVote);

        $em->flush();

        return $user;
    }

    $data = $this->formErrorHelper->convertFormToErrorApiResponse($form);

    return $this->view($data, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track there, but you miss a key element. After resetting the entity manager you need to select your entities again and this is a better anyway.

Here is a great blog post with example: [link](https://medium.com/lebouchondigital/thread-safe-business-logic-with-doctrine-f09c633f6554)

Comment: Hello Alexander, I tried resetting and selecting the entities again but the current user is retrieved with `$user = $this->getUser()`. How can I retrieve it again? Same thing for the `ChallengeEntry` object in the method. Thanks.